# jQuery for toggling menu on Wordpress not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress site that has a sub-menu I need to open when a certain 'li' is clicked and close when it's clicked again. I've tried several jQuery functions and nothing is working.

I've also included the `wp_enqueue_script` function in the `functions.php` file, and I know the script referenced is working because I added a simple alert function to my created jQuery file and it works.

Here is the HTML of the menu:

```
<nav id="access" class="clearfix">
    <div class="container clearfix">
      <ul class="root">

         <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-19">
         <a href="example.com/">my name</a></li>

         <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-17">
         <a href="example.com/?page_id=10">film</a>
             <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-43">
                  <a href="example.com/?page_id=42">calvin klein film</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22">
                  <a href="example.com/?page_id=20">cam’ron</a></li>
               .
               .
               .
             </ul>

           </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- .container -->
</nav>
```

So when `menu-item-17` is clicked, I need the sub-menu class to appear and then disappear on another click.

I've tried functions like this with no luck:

```
jQuery("#menu-item-17").click(function () {
$(".sub-menu").toggle("slow");
});
```

And in case it helps, here's what I added in the `functions.php` file:

```
function attitude_child_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('toggle js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/toggle.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'attitude_child_scripts');
```

What am I doing wrong?? Is it something Wordpress specific? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `jQuery(".sub-menu").toggle("slow");`

Comment: @roullie Just tried that and no luck. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I found in your javscript is that you are trying to toggle the visibity of the
submenu class but the #menu-item-17 li contains a link.  The link will navigate to url contained within its href attribute by default.  To prevent the link from executing its default behavior you would have to change your javascript to the code below:  jsfiddle example --> http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/206duwnt/

Javascript code:

```
 /* 
jQuery document ready function call below is used passing $ as a parameter in order to avoid any conflicts with other Jquery Libraries loaded that might use the $ in its library
*/


jQuery(document).ready(function($){//begin document ready wrapper function to allow the use of the $

 //hide .sub-menu element on page load
 $(".sub-menu").hide();

/*
Adding e as a function parameter, e is as a variable that holds the event object. Child selector plus a added so that the preventDefault
only affects links that are a direct child of #menu-item-17.
*/
    $("#menu-item-17 > a").click(function(e){//begin click event

    /* 
    The code was added below because if you click on the #menu-item-17
    li element it contains a link which will navigate by default.
    */
    e.preventDefault();


$(".sub-menu").toggle("slow");

});//end click event

});//end document ready wrapper function
```

If you want to keep the link in the #menu-item-17 li element, You could place another element
beside it in the li so that the user could click on the new element to toggle visibility. This could be some plain text or an image. You could also move the link to another li element all together.  If you make any of these changes then you would want to remove the e.preventDefault() function call so that your link in the #menu-item-17 li element will navigate to another page again.

Comment: That makes sense. I tried it on my site and for some reason it's still not working -- the toggle or preventing the link from doing the default. I do want to prevent that. Maybe it's something in the Wordpress theme code that's over-riding it?

Comment: Try right clicking on the element you want to click on. The click on inspect element. When the debug console appears click on the console tag.  Then click on the button to see if you get any javascript errors.  Let me know what happens and we can go from there.

Comment: I followed your steps and no javascript errors showing up for my file. I'm getting a few saying SyntaxError: Parser Error (anonymous function), but it's for another js file included with the theme.

Comment: Do you have a link to the website?

Comment: elizabethdesimone.com

Right now the sub-menu is set to 'display:block' in CSS, but I've tried it set to 'none' also.

Comment: I am working on the problem right now. I believe I have found it and I will update my answer once I am certain it is correct.

Comment: Ok I have make the proper corrections to the code.  There was a conflict somewhere with another javascript library that is loaded in your website. I discovered this error in firefox debug console: TypeError: $ is not a function which led me to the fix

Comment: It works!! Thank you so, so much @Larry Lane. What a relief. Now I just had one more question... ideas on what to change so that the .sub-menu will be hidden first then show on the toggle? Right now it does the opposite.

Comment: Never mind, I figured that out. However, the links in the sub-menu don't work. It seems to be from the preventDefault... do you know of a way to keep it from affecting those links?

Comment: I got it to work with 'menu-item-17 > a'. Thanks again!!